# MySQL Distinct Query Error

Tags: php, sql, distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT(reserve_dummy.isbn) as reserved_dummy.isbn,
       reserved_dummy.price,
       reserved_dummy.qty,
       reserved_dummy.date,
       reserved_dummy.total 
FROM reserved_dummy
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>   '.isbn,reserved_dummy.price,reserved_dummy.qty,reserved_dummy.date,reserved_dummy'
>   at line 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT(reserve_dummy.isbn) as reserved_dummy.isbn,
       reserved_dummy.price,
       reserved_dummy.qty,
       reserved_dummy.date,
       reserved_dummy.total 
FROM reserved_dummy
```

kindly help me figure out my wrong here. thanks in advance

Comment: do not use dots `.` for aliases without backticks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(isbn) AS isbn,
       price,qty,
       date,total 
FROM reserved_dummy
```

The syntax for the SQL DISTINCT clause is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT columns FROM tables
```

Don't use `.` (dot) operator when aliasing

Answer (score 0):

Just quit that strange idea of prefixing every field name with table name

```
SELECT DISTINCT(isbn) as isbn,price,qty,date,total FROM reserved_dummy
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the table prefix when using the `SELECT DISTINCT(x.y) AS x.y ....` syntax, it should be `SELECT DISTINCT(x.y) AS y ....`

Take this out and the query should work:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(reserve_dummy.isbn) as isbn,
    reserved_dummy.price,
    reserved_dummy.qty,
    reserved_dummy.date,
    reserved_dummy.total 
FROM 
    reserved_dummy
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do such a query. You can do a

```
select distinct isbn, price, qty, date, total from reserved_dummy
```

and you'll get the distinct records.

However, I don't see what do you want to get from this query.

Maybe isbn is the primary key, in that case:

```
select `isbn`, `price`, `qty`, `date` from reserved_dummy
```

should work.

Note the backquote sign around fieldnames. That's because "date" is a function name in MySQL and using it as fieldname without the quotes will fail.

If it happens that there're several records with the same isbn, and you want to get the data from the newest one you could do a query like:

```
select `isbn`, `price`, `qty`, `date`
from reserved_dummy
where (`isbn`, `date`) in (
    select isbn, max(`date`) from reserved_dummy group by isbn
)
```

to get what you're looking for.